# Asp.Net Javascript compilation Error: "Identifier Expected"

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having problem with following code.
Its showing compliation error:- "Identifier Expected".

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat = "server">
function isOverElement(currentElement, targetId)
        {
            while (currentElement)
            {
                if (currentElement.id == targetId)
                    return currentElement;

                currentElement = currentElement.parentNode;
            }

            return null;
        }
</script>
```

The problem is in line:-
**function isOverElement(currentElement, targetId)**
Rest all is OK, I suppose.

please help.
thnx

Comment: I assume that this is a js-function and not a C# function. So remove the runat=server.

Comment: What do you want to do with 'while (currentElement)' ? In my eyes it is a very bad coding style and often resonsible for lots of errors.

Comment: @ reporter, actually the lines inside the function is not cause for the error I'm getting. i'm pretty sure for it.

Comment: @tim:- absolutely correct. thanks

Comment: @ALL:- CHOOSING Darin Dimitrov's ANSWER AS BEST ANSWER... as it was fastest response. Just before JQONE. Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `runat="server"` attribute from your `<script>` tag. Javascript runs on the client, not on the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isOverElement(currentElement, targetId) {
        while (currentElement) {
            if (currentElement.id == targetId)
                return currentElement;

            currentElement = currentElement.parentNode;
        }

        return null;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need runat="server" for script tag. Try removing the runat and see if it working

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the tag runat="server" since you have written a pure javascript function.

Change

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat = "server">  to  <script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: thanks for the letting me know the reason for removing runat = "server" tag.